# p:dataTable pdf export and page break between columns

Tags: primefaces, datatable, itext, export

I would like to know if it's possible to put a break page when a datatable have many columns.

I used a p:columns to create my datatable and it has more than 40 columns.
When i try to export this table to a pdf, all columns are display on one page so nothing can be show. 
I would like to put a size to columns and print few columns by page

for exemple  :

page 1

col 1|col 2|col 3|col 4|col 5|col 6|col 7|

page 2
col 8|col 9|col 10|col 11|col 12|col 13|col 14|

etc.

When i export the table on excel i can print it like this but i can't do a pdf with this format.

I have implemented a PDFCustomExporter and ExcelCustomExporter - primefaces extension - but i can't change width and do a page break to the pdf file

PS : a solution i have found is to create a PDF with a large width (A0 format for example) but it's not a "good" solution

Sorry for my bad english but i Hope you could understand my problem :) 
Thanks for your help, 
Regards
Tifred

Comment: This is kind of a usecase for which the PF PDF exporter was not really intended. I think you should try to use a real reporting tool for exports like this.

Comment: I am confused why this question is tagged with iText, can you please explain?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer 
 - AmedeeVanGasse I don't tag "iText"  but iText is used by the primefaces extension for the PDFCustomExporter
 - Kukeltje Do you know one good tool to do this ?